# C++: Am I managing memory the right way?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Also, how would I go about putting my class in another file? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Array
{

int *arrayPointer;
public:

  Array(int size);
  ~Array(); 

  int get(int index);
  void set(int index, int value);

protected:
  int array[];
  int size;
};

Array::Array(int theSize){
  size = theSize;
  arrayPointer = new int[size]; 
}

Array::~Array(){
  delete[] arrayPointer;
}

int Array::get(int index){
  return *(arrayPointer + index);
}

void Array::set(int index, int value){
  if(index >= size || index < 0){
    cout << "Ooops, index out of bounds" << endl;
  }
  else{
    *(arrayPointer + index) = value;
  }
}

/* Let's see it in action now! */

int main(){
  int size = 3;
  Array array (size);
  array.set(0, 1);
  array.set(1, 2);
  array.set(2,3);
  cout << "Index 0 = " << array.get(0) << endl;
  cout << "Index 1 = " << array.get(1) << endl;
  cout << "Index 2 = " << array.get(2) << endl;
  array.set(4, 3);
  array.set(-1, 2);
}
```

Comment: At least IMO, not very well, no. I wrote a rather [lengthy post](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html) about this recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you have no copy constructor (or assignment operator). This will be a problem in this case:

```
void foo(Array a) {
   //...
}

int main() {
   Array a(10);
   foo(a);
   //a is still around, but the pointer has been destroyed.
}
```

Since there will be two instances of Array using the same pointer. Once one of them goes out of scope, the destructor is called, so the delete[] happens. However, there is still *another* instance of Array with that same pointer, which has no way to know that delete happened. This is solved by following the "[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)" See "[Dynamically allocating an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255612/14065) for a simple example.

In second place, you have a member called `array`. What's it for? It's never used so why have it?

In third place, some members are `protected`. Why? Does this mean you plan to have Array be inherited? In that case, you might want to make the destructor virtual. But I'd advise *against* inheritance, as it would feel counter-intuitive.

The implementation of `get` and `set` use unnecessary pointer arithmetic.
Just do:

```
return arrayPointer[index];
```

This does the same thing and it's much cleaner to look at.

In fourth place, you do a check on the values of index for `set`, but not for `get`. Why not?

In fifth place, index is a signed integer. You may want to consider using `size_t` instead. It will also make the `< 0` check redundant.

In sixth place, usage of `get` and `set` feels unnatural. You may want to look at *operator overloading*.

In seventh place, I would not use `cout` for the error message. Use `assert()`, `cerr` or an exception, depending on what your exact needs are.

In eighth place, you call it `Array` but you only allow integers to be stored. I'd either name it `IntArray` or make it a template to allow other types to be stored.

As for "Putting your class in another file", that might be a good idea, especially if you want `Array` to be used in multiple files. Put it in a header file.

Also, why create your own `Array` class? Is this for learning purposes? If not, you may want to use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Very helpful! And yes it is for learning purposes, I just wanted to play around with pointer arithmetic and learn some basics of C++. My issue now is, how do I go about putting my class in a header file and linking it up.

So far what I understand is, the class definition goes in a .h file, but the actual implementation of functions go in another. I don't understand how to get that last part to work though . . .

Comment: @Breedly You could have an "array.cpp" and an "array.h". "array.cpp" would `#include "array.h"`. `class Array{ ... }` would go in the header, `Array::stuff` would go in the C++. Either that, or you could merge the whole thing in the header, with `class Array { Array(int theSize) { size = theSize; } ... }`.

Answer (score 4):

Two quick things:

---

Always make single variable constructors explicit (unless you actually want implicit construction, but you very rarely should).

```
 void f(Array a) { }
 f(5); //<-- runs fine.  basically does Array(5).
```

---

Unless a class is specifically designed to handle output (a logging adapter, a formatter, etc), you shouldn't have output in a class.

What if this Array class were to be used in a GUI based application?  That `cout` would be useless then.  luiscubal suggested either assert or `cerr`, but I would argue that you should either throw an exception or give the method a bool return and return a flag of whether or not it was set. (There's no particularly pleasant way to recover from a failed assert, and `cerr` has the same problem of putting output in a class that has no business doing output.)